# Spring security - implement oauth with existing FilterChainProxy

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

we have existing web application built with Spring security 3.1 ,Wink(for rest) 
we now need to add oauth2 (client_credentials flow) for several resources, i looked into many examples and all of them using the Http namespace configuration along with spring dispatcher servlet (which we didn't have till now)

problem is that http namespace is creating a springSecurityFilterChain which we already had in the application , so first thing i renamed the existing filter so the default could co-exist with the old one.
but this does not work, its either the existing chain working for requests or the new one.
i have tried the following already
1. disabled dispatcher servlet context by giving empty config location (in web.xml)
2. tried to have the oauth configuration in application-context.xml (right to the existing FilterChainProxy)
3. Allow the /oauth/token in existing chain by setting its filter to none (so the new can take over)
4. tried to declare the oauth filters in the existing chain but there was a problem with its not getting the right clientAuthentication

i really don't know what else to try - so the question is : is it possible to have both declared in the same webapp ? or is it possible to declare oauth2 configuration in the old fashion.

thanks
Shlomi

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do that eventually, having the API (protected with oauth) completey separated url from the rest of the application.
so the Http namespace is creating the springSecurityFilterChain bean and the others just have different bean names. everyone is delegated through the DelegatingProxy in web.xml

i needed to puth the API URL prefix in other chains and allow all requests through , leaving the oauth security chanin to deal with security.
(i.e filter-chain pattern="/api/**" filters="none)

regarding the spring oauth2 bounded to spring MVC so tight i think is not a good implementation.
the mapping of the dispatcher servlet cannot be for /* but have to be something like /auth/*

so a special filter inherit from ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter with special path like super("/auth/oauth/token") was needed.

it also cannot be /api/* since this is the real API URI mapped by our rest framework (wink RestServlet)
so we have something like this

```
http://server:port/context/auth/oauth/token
http://server:port/context/api/someresource (protected with oauth2)
http://server:port/context/rest/someresource (old rest for application)
```

Shlomi